# MySQL Character sets

Tags: mysql

If I need a varchar(30) field, for example, that needs to contain several different foreign character sets, is there one particular language type that I can use in MySQL?  For example, I have a field contains names in Chinese, Russian, English, Spanish and Portuguese, and possibly more in the future.  How do I enable this for a varchar() field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode can contain every character in use worldwide.

be sure to use UTF-8 for the field.  (better yet, for the whole database).

Answer (score 0):

**utf-8** is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

**utf8mb4** should be the answers there days.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.